# How to make the Extended Display desktop picture the correct size?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi, desktop

I am using a 24" Samsung Monitor (Connected via HDMI with a highest possible resolution of 1920x1080) to a Windows 7 laptop (Toshiba with a highest possible resolution of 1366x768).

When I extend the display from my computer with the resolution of the monitor set to 1920x1080 I can use the whole screen all 1920x1080 pixels but my desktop image just sits in the middle leaving a large black border. How can I upscale (or something like that) the desktop picture so that it will fill the the whole monitor screen. My image is not too small either it is 3513x2361 pixels.

Thanks in advance
Niels

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are [extending](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976064) (and not duplicating) the monitors? By design, the wallpaper which you set is used for both the monitors in Win7 (unless you use some tools)

If you are indeed extending, you can use a simple hack and create your wallpaper the size and width of both monitors combined and apply them in 'stretch' mode.

Comment: One is the laptop screen and the other is the monitor screen. It duplicates the background onto the extended display but is is definitely extended. And when you say a simple hack, I'm not clear on what you mean??

Comment: Ok, lets say your laptop screen is A x B size and monitor is C x D then you simply create a wallpaper with width = A+C and height B+D. Then apply it in stretched mode (not fill)

Comment: I tried this method. I made the picture the exact size and said stretch but it still didn't work. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you try applying it in 'fit' mode ?

Comment: I have tried  all the desktop background applications (fit, stretch, fill etc) none of them do anything. I read somewhere that ti